# Ruby on Rails: Getting undefined method using array with name in my select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can someone explain to me why I'm getting undefined method when I add `day[]` (an array) to my select tag

```
<%= form_for [@hourable, @hour] do |f| %>
  <%= f.select 'day[]', options_for_select(days_hours) %>
<% end %>
```

But when I have it like this `:day`:

```
<%= form_for [@hourable, @hour] do |f| %>
  <%= f.select :day, options_for_select(days_hours) %>
<% end %>
```

It works fine?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `f.select` helper, the first argument is *the property* you want to assign. There is no property `day[]`. What you need here is `:multiple => true` option. So, it will look like:

```
f.select(:day, options_for_select(days_hours), {}, :multiple => true)
```

For more information, see the [docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper/select)

Comment: Oh okay thanks! `:multiple => true` allows to select multiple items in one select field right? So what if I want separate the select fields, say two different select fields but same name, would I have to just change `f.select` to `select_tag`? Thanks

Comment: Yes, then you need select_tag, as rails won't do the magic for you in that case.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `select_tag` helper:

```
<%= select_tag "days[]", options_for_select(days_hours), {:multiple => :multiple} %>
```

It's only another option. Roman's answer give you what you wanted.

Hope it helps :)